# Expectation of a product of increasing functions of a positive random variable

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

In the proof of Theorem 3.3 in "An introduction to Stein's method" by Barbour and Chen we can read

> [...] since both $x^2$ and $x \wedge 1$ are increasing functions of $x \ge 0$, it follows that, for any random variable $\xi$,
>   $\mathbb{E}[\xi^2]\mathbb{E}[|\xi| \wedge 1] \le \mathbb{E}[\xi^2|\xi| \wedge 1]$ [...]

I take this to refer to a claim:

Let $f,g : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ be non-decreasing functions and let $X$ be a non-negative random variable. Then $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]\mathbb{E}[g(X)] \le \mathbb{E}[f(X)g(X)]$.

My question is: why is this claim true? I've tried to prove it but I haven't made any progress. I'm very grateful for any answers or hints on how to show it.

Comment: Is there more to the right side of the inequality indicated by the [...], or does that just mean the text goes on then and says more?

Comment: Probably the assumption $X \geq 0$ is not required if this claim is true. Since $f$ and $g$ are functions, it shouldn't really matter what lower bound $X$ has (although it might be required that there is SOME lower bound). I think the author meant that the function $x^2$ is increasing for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: @coffeemath Another inequality follows, but this is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @user2566092 Yes, that makes sense!

Comment: Was discussed recently: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446477/show-mathbbefxgx-geq-mathbbefx-mathbbegx-for-f-g-boun/1446535#1446535

Comment: @zhoraster Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One way to see this is as a limiting argument of the rearrangement inequality (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality ). If you approximate $f,g$ by step functions on intervals of width $\epsilon > 0$, then if you consider $n$ consecutive intervals and let $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ and $g_i,\ldots,g_n$ be the values of your step function approximation on the $n$ intervals, then the left side of your inequality (applied to the step functions) is $(1/n^2) \sum_{ij}f_ig_j$ and the right side of your inequality is $(1/n) \sum_i f_i g_i$. You can view the left side as $n$ sums of $n$ products, where each set of $n$ products has each $f_i$ and each $g_i$ appearing once.  (One of these sums is $\sum_i f_i g_i$ and the others are obtained by circularly shifting the indices of the $g_i$ while keeping the indices of the $f_i$ fixed.) The rearrangement inequality thus says the left side is less than or equal to the right side. Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ gives you the inequality for the entire step function approximations. Then taking $\epsilon \to 0$ gives the final desired result for $f,g$.

Note that the only assumption needed is that $f,g$ are (weakly) increasing.

UPDATE: The answer given basically assumes $X$ takes on values uniformly in some interval. But even if not, and even if $X$ has point masses, the values that $X$ takes on can be "split" into bins where the probability mass of $X$ within each bin is the same. This may require breaking point masses into fractional parts. As long as the bins for $X$ are ordered (for $i < j$, all the values of $X$ in bin $i$ are less than or equal to the values of $X$ in bin $j$), the argument for $f$ and $g$ will still go through.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you correctly. Provided that it is possible to choose the consecutive intervals $I_k$ such that $P(X \in I_k) = 1/n$, then yes, the inequality should hold and it seems probable that it holds in the limit as well, although I need to brush up on my integration theory to be able to prove this. In this case, however, the intervals will have different lengths. Could you explain where the $\epsilon (1/n^2)$ and $\epsilon (1/n)$ terms come from?

Comment: @AndreasPetersson The $\epsilon$ in the expectation was a mistake. I updated my answer to explain how to push the argument through even when $X$ is not uniformly distributed (and may even have point masses).